# Fire an event using webhooks from dropbox when some file is uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox, webhooks

I have an application in which, when a file is uploaded on dropbox, an event should be triggered in asp.net to notify that file is uploaded on dropbox.

Comment: Please read [ask], take the [tour] and see what questions you should [avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I'm voting to close as this isn't even a question at the moment. If you're asking something, you should ask it.